# Image with max-width & max-height transition, gets larger before resizing correctly

Tags: html, css, image, transition, image-resizing

I'm dynamically resizing an image with max-width and max-height (I need both). I have a button which changes the page-layout and inverts the image's max-width and max-height with a transition by toggling a class.
The problem is that the image when resizing gets bigger before it resizes correctly.
Note that this does not happen when simply resizing the viewport.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0s1Ljtxt/3/) - switch between up & down to see what I mean.

CSS:

```
.viewer {
    display: inline-block;
}

.viewer img {
    max-width: 41.36vw; max-height: 90.16vh;
    margin: 1.19vh 0.64vw;
    display: block;
    transition: all 2s;
}

#content.vertical img {
    max-width: 90.16vw; max-height: 41.36vh;
    margin: 0.64vh 1.19vw;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<section id="welkomContent">
        <h1>Welkom</h1>
        <div class="contentWrapper"><div class="contentContainer">
            <div class="viewer">
                <img src="http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/36600000/Lions-image-lions-36609573-1440-900.jpg" alt="Portret"/>
            </div>
        </div></div>
    </section>
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: say exact what you want, I amn't understand your point.

Comment: In the Fiddle, when switching between "up" and "down", the image first gets bigger, and then smaller again (to the intended size). It should resize to the intended size WITHOUT getting bigger first.
Hope that gets my point across.

Answer (score 0):

Live view [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/0s1Ljtxt/4/)

You need to removed 
  `transition: all 2s;` From `.contentWrapper` and  `.viewer img` both .
Check my jsfiddle right now is solved.

Comment: so you can use it by especially for exact element not for ALL

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: as like `transition width, color 2s`

Comment: Oh, but the point is that I want the image resize to be animated.
I've tried with an animation instead of a transition, but the problem remains.
I suspect that it's because max-width and max-height aren't animated simultaneously, or something.
Thanks though! I might have to use JQuery for this.